# Datatable Column Exceeds

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I got a huge dataset with around 39 columns. Now the datatable exceeds the display area of the browser.
No problem with rows is they are listed based on pagination. Is there any wrapping property to datatables? I want to display all columns in the same browser space

My datatable columns are

```
<table id='datatable' class="ui celled table" style='width:100%'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>DeviceID</th>
            <th>AppID</th>
            <th>IsFingerprint</th>
            <th>CurrentDate</th>
            <th>IsSDCard</th>
            <th>NetworkType</th>
            <th>TotalRAM</th>
            <th>AvailInternal</th>
            <th>AvailExternal</th>
            <th>TotalInternal</th>
            <th>TotalExternal</th>
            <th>Activity</th>
            <th>Package</th>
            <th>AppStore</th>
            <th>AppName</th>
            <th>AppVersion</th>
            <th>AppVersionCode</th>
            <th>BatteryCharge</th>
            <th>IsCharging</th>
            <th>Manufacturer</th>
            <th>Model</th>
            <th>OSCodename</th>
            <th>OSVersion</th>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Device</th>
            <th>Board</th>
            <th>Hardware</th>
            <th>Rooted</th>
            <th>Brand</th>
            <th>Host</th>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>User</th>
            <th>ScreenResolution</th>
            <th>ScreenDensity</th>
            <th>ScreenSize</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Carrier</th>
            <th>ActiveTraffic</th>
            <th>AppUsage</th>
            <th>Image</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>DeviceID</th>
            <th>AppID</th>
            <th>IsFingerprint</th>
            <th>CurrentDate</th>
            <th>IsSDCard</th>
            <th>NetworkType</th>
            <th>TotalRAM</th>
            <th>AvailInternal</th>
            <th>AvailExternal</th>
            <th>TotalInternal</th>
            <th>TotalExternal</th>
            <th>Activity</th>
            <th>Package</th>
            <th>AppStore</th>
            <th>AppName</th>
            <th>AppVersion</th>
            <th>AppVersionCode</th>
            <th>BatteryCharge</th>
            <th>IsCharging</th>
            <th>Manufacturer</th>
            <th>Model</th>
            <th>OSCodename</th>
            <th>OSVersion</th>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Device</th>
            <th>Board</th>
            <th>Hardware</th>
            <th>Rooted</th>
            <th>Brand</th>
            <th>Host</th>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>User</th>
            <th>ScreenResolution</th>
            <th>ScreenDensity</th>
            <th>ScreenSize</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Carrier</th>
            <th>ActiveTraffic</th>
            <th>AppUsage</th>
            <th>Image</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

I use **AJAX** to load data from my **PHP API** endpoint and it works fine.
Is there any way to merge cells like **AppName, AppPackage, AppVersion, AppVersionCode** comes under App cell

Comment: You should use a container with a horizontal scroll.. And vertical.. you can read more at https://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_x.html

Comment: Hey. This is what I'm looking so far. Submit it as an answer and I will mark it. Thanks